A question about $=_\beta$ in Lambda Calculus
In Theorem 3.33, I do not understand why the expression $(U_3^3)^{n+1}U_1^2 =_{\beta}U_2^2$ after "because" in the proof of it holds. Relevant definitions are also attached after Theorem 3.33:
Theorem 3.33: There exists $D \in \Lambda^\circ$, such that $D\lceil 0\rceil =_{\beta}U_1^2, D\lceil n+1\rceil =_{\beta}U_2^2,$ therefore $D\lceil 0\rceil MN =_{\beta}M,\\D\lceil n+1\rceil MN =_{\beta}N.$
Proof: Let $D \equiv [U_3^3, U_1^2]$, because $(U_3^3)^{n+1}U_1^2 =_{\beta}U_2^2,$ thus $D\lceil 0\rceil =_{\beta} U_1^2; D\lceil n+1\rceil =_{\beta} U_2^2.$
Here are some Definitions and Propositions:
Definition 3.32
(1) $U_i^n \equiv \lambda x_1...x_n.x_i$, where $n \geq 1$ and $1 \leq i \le n$;
(2) For $n \geq 1$, $M_1, ..., M_n \in \Lambda$, define $[M_1, ..., M_n] \equiv \lambda z.zM_1...M_n$, where $z$ is a new variable not appearing in $M_1, ..., M_n$.
(3) $(M)_i^n \equiv MU_i^n$, where $n \geq 1$ and $1 \leq i \le n$
Proposition 3.25 For $n \geq 1$ and $1 \leq i \le n$, $([M_1, ..., M_n])_i^n \twoheadrightarrow_{\beta}M_i$
My idea is that $(U_3^3)^{n+1}$ acts as an $n$-level function, with the innermost level acting on $U_1^2$. The result of the innermost layer might be $\lambda xyz.z(U_1^2) =_{\beta} z$, and then the result $z$ is applied as the argument to the first parameter of the outer layer, which would be $\lambda xyz'.z'(z) =_{\beta} z$. Therefore, after being applied $n$ times, the result should also be $z$ ? I am not sure how this leads to the result $U_2^2$, and I would appreciate it if you could point out any issues with my reasoning.
p.s I use "$\lceil n \rceil$" to represent the Church Coding.

Three dashes a row --- in the Markdown produce the divider you want :)

You have $U^3_3 = \lambda x y z. z = KU^2_2$, where $K = \lambda x y. x$ is the constant combinator, so applying $U^3_3$ any nonzero number of times to a term results in $U^2_2$.

It seems that $K U_2^2={\beta}(\lambda xy.x)(\lambda ab.b)={\beta}\lambda ab.b$ doesn't directly produce an expression equivalent to $\lambda x_1 x_2 x_3.x_3$? Could you please show the detailed derivation process?

You got that wrong. $(\lambda xy. x)(\lambda ab. b) \to_\beta \lambda y. \lambda ab. b =_\alpha \lambda x_1 x_2 x_3. x_3$.

Thanks for your explanation! I got it~


The result of the innermost layer might be $λxyz.z(U^2_1)=_βz$, and then the result $z$ is applied as the argument to the first parameter of the outer layer, which would be $λxyz′.z′(z)=_βz$. Therefore, after being applied $n$ times, the result should also be $z$ ?

There is no unbound $z$.   You have $\mathrm U_3^3(\mathrm U_1^2)=(\lambda xyz.z)(\mathrm U_1^2)$.   (Remember to delimit the scope of the abstraction to avoid mixing other things in.)
The application of $\mathrm U_3^3$ returns the third of three terms.  The result of applying it to one term is to skip it, and then wait for two more terms so it may return second; that is, it returns the abstraction: $\mathrm U_2^2$.
$$\begin{align}\mathrm U_3^3\, t &=_\delta (\lambda x_1.\lambda x_2.\lambda x_3.x_3)\,t\\ &=_\beta\lambda x_2.\lambda x_3.x_3\\ &=_\alpha \lambda x_1.\lambda x_2.x_2\\ &=_\delta \mathrm U_2^2\end{align}$$
The identity of term $t$ does not actually matter.
So, since $\mathrm U_3^3$ always returns the single term $\mathrm U_2^2$ whenever supplied a single term, and the abstraction, $\mathrm U_1^2$, is also a single term, then...
$$\mathrm U_3^3 (\mathrm U^3_3(\ldots(\mathrm U_3^3(\mathrm U_1^2))\ldots))) = \mathrm U_2^2$$
